# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar data extracts en el Servidor de Tableau con jobs de Autosys?

Tags: windows

Quisiera poder crear un job en Autosys para que actualice los data extracts o data sources en Tableau Server.

Comment: Hola, bienvenida a StackOverflow en español . Para que recibas feedback adecuado de la comunidad por favor complementa tu pregunta, añade detalles como las cosas que has intentado y los errores que estas obteniendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Tableau Server existen unos comandos especiales llamados TABCMD (http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/extracting_TDE.html) para controlar los data extracts y otras funciones desde la línea de comandos en Windows. Este es un ejemplo que se puede utilizar para actualizar los data extracts con un archivo batch:

Va directo al directorio donde se encuentra TABCMD ((x86 si el servidor         está en 32 bits))

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tableau\Tableau Server\9.1\bin"
```

Entra en el servidor para poder tener acceso a los data extracts

```
TABCMD login -s *nombre_servidor* -u *nombre_usuario* -p *contraseña*
```

Se hace la actualización de los data extracts

```
TABCMD refreshextracts --project *nombre_proyecto* --datasource      *nombre_datasource*
```

La información que está entre asteriscos se puede pasar por parámetros desde la consola, y también se puede aplicar manejo de errores con la variable ERRORLEVEL de batch. El código se copia en un archivo en blanco en el bloc de notas y se guarda con la extensión .batch.

Esta parte es para actualizar los data extracts; Para poder aplicarlo con Autosys, hay que instalar Autosys Remote Agent en el servidor de Tableau para poder crear un job que ejecute el archivo batch que estará dentro del servidor. Autosys tendrá que tener una cuenta con privilegios administrativos para poder ejecutar el archivo batch con el job.

Comment: gracias por compartir la respuesta, cuando puedas trata de marcarla como correcta.